# Need help try the write a script with day date and time

Tags: javascript

Do not know what i'm doing wrong and would like some help to fix it i am trying to make script to write out the day date and time like this It is currently: 3:15 PM on Wednesday, September 21. this is what i have

```
function renderTime(){
var mydate = new date();
var year = mydate.getYear();
    if(year < 1000){
        year +=1900
    }
var day = mydate.getDay();
var month = mydate.getMonth();
var daym = mydate.getDate();
var dayarray = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var montharray = new Array("Jannuary","Februry","March","April","May","June","July","Augest","September","October","November","December");

var currentTime = new Date();
var h = currentTime.getHour();
var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
 if(h == 24){
        h = 0;
    } else if (h > 12 ){
        h = h - 0;
    }
    if(h < 10){
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    if(m < 10){
        m = "0" + m;
    }
}

document.write("It is currently"+h+m+"on"+dayarray[day]+ montharray[month]+daym);
```

Comment: If you're allowed to use an external library, check out [day.js](https://day.js.org/) which will make your life so much easier.

Comment: Just use toLocalString, is this scenario it's better to use toLocaleDate & toLocaleTime:
https://jsfiddle.net/xg27m90q/

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66252571/9078341) is the correct approach to take with date and time processing. You should consider up voting and accepting that answer. Others will suggest other libraries like day.js or moment.js etc. You don't need to add 2000 lines of code to do something that can be done with a few lines of well written, well informed code.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify it by using toLocaleDateString and toLocaleTimeString:

```js
var myDate = (new Date()).toLocaleDateString("en-US", {weekday: 'long',month: 'long',day: 'numeric'});
var myTime = (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString("en-US", {hour: 'numeric',minute: 'numeric'
});
var message = 'It is currently: ' + myTime + ' on ' + myDate;
console.log(message);
```

Comment: This is the best answer of them all. I made it runnable to so other can understand what you've done. This is so much better than including 1000s of lines of library code to do something this simple.

Comment: FYI, you don't really need the `()` around `new Date()`

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank, I knew for the (), it's mainly for readability. I should also be using `console.log(\`It is currently: ${myTime} on ${myDate}\`)` for it to be cleaner. But I believe he has to use the 1000s line of code as this look like a first year homework to learn how to use modulo, if, else, elseif, array

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mydate = new Date();
var year = mydate.getYear();
    if(year < 1000){
        year +=1900
    }
var day = mydate.getDay();
var month = mydate.getMonth();
var daym = mydate.getDate();
var dayarray = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var montharray = new Array("Jannuary","Februry","March","April","May","June","July","Augest","September","October","November","December");

var currentTime = new Date();
var h = currentTime.getHours();
var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
 if(h == 24){
        h = 0;
    } else if (h > 12 ){
        h = h - 12;
    }
    if(h < 10){
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    if(m < 10){
        m = "0" + m;
    }


document.write("It is currently "+h+ ":"+ m+ ampm +" on "+dayarray[day] + ' ' +  montharray[month] + ' '+daym);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let dateString = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US").split("/");
// returns an array ["month", "day as number in month", "year"]
let timeString = new Date().toLocaleTimeString("en-US").split(/:| /);
// returns an array ["hour", "minute", "second", "am or pm"]
let weekDayNumber = new Date().getDay();
let days = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];
let months = ["Jannuary","Februry","March","April","May","June","July","Augest","September","October","November","December"];
document.write("It is currently"+timeString[0]+timeString[1]+"on"+days[weekDayNumber ]+ months[dateString[0]]+dateString[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're running all your date rendering in a function which keeps all your interim variables private. This is a good thing, but you're not providing any way to get the result out. Include a `return` statement in your function to return the formatted string like this:

```
return ("It is currently "+h+":"+m+" on "+dayarray[day]+" "+ montharray[month]+" "+daym);
```

You create a new Date object for time, but you should just use the one you created for date, and you missed a letter of a method name. Here's the revised version:

```
function renderTime(){
var mydate = new Date();
var year = mydate.getYear();
    if(year < 1000){
        year +=1900
    }
var day = mydate.getDay();
var month = mydate.getMonth();
var daym = mydate.getDate();
var dayarray = new Array("Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var montharray = new Array("January","Februry","March","April","May","June","July","Augest","September","October","November","December");


// re-use mydate here instead of creating a new object.
var h = mydate.getHours();          // You missed the 's' off 'getHours()'
var m = mydate.getMinutes();
var ampm = h >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
 if(h == 24){
        h = 0;
    } else if (h > 12 ){
        h = h - 0;
    }
    if(h < 10){
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    if(m < 10){
        m = "0" + m;
    }

// Return the result. Added some spaces to pretty it up a bit
return ("It is currently "+h+":"+m+ampm+" on "+dayarray[day]+" "+ montharray[month]+" "+daym);
}

// Now output the return value of the function.
document.write(renderTime());
```